# C# WCF Service Result

Tags: c#, wcf, transport-security

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm= Default Realm '.--The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm= Default Realm '.

Hi,

what is the meaning of the result which I mentioned above. I got this error message from one of services. It was working before I update the service reference.

You can see web.configuration belove

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MCCI_AR000001TR_Binding">
                <security mode="Transport"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client><endpoint address="https://ws.sagliknet.saglik.gov.tr/WSMuayene" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MCCI_AR000001TR_Binding" contract="MuayeneServiceReference.MCCI_AR000001TR_PortType" name="MCCI_AR000001TR_Port"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please post your configurations, you have certainly a mismatch between your client and server one.

Comment: Please edit your post, do not add it as a comment. Then you must publish the full service configuration, i.e. everything in the <system.serviceModel> element.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to set the configuration as basic credential and you need also to pass you credential prior to create a channel.

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MCCI_AR000001TR_Binding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: ClientCredentials.UserName.Password and also  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName has been setted but still I have the same problem.